# Glassfish and Tomcat error

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, jakarta-ee, glassfish-4

I am using Eclipse Java EE IDE (dynamic web project). I encountered a problem with my server that I downloaded to the eclipse. The server I am using is Tomcat v8.0 and I tried glassfish4.
When I run the servers to test my work, it shows these messages.

see for tomcat:

[image: tomcat]

see for glassfish4:

[image: glassfish]

Note the servers was working perfectly few days ago but it stopped working suddenly. I tried deleting the servers and reinstalling many times them again but it did not work.

Comment: Check tomcat and glassfish logs. And glassfish uses 8080 as default port, which is being used by tomcat. It is better to understand it from logs.

Comment: Is there a trace on the Server log that can be used for troubleshooting ? Can you check if the server logs contain any specific stack trace ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with one of the JAR files that caused the server to be down so I just replaced this Jar file.

Answer (score 0):

Go to *Servers* explorer.
Try cleaning the server, I think you have already done that.
Try deleting the server from explorer. After that explorer will show a link *No servers are available. Click this link..* Click on it and then select the server name *Tomcat v8.0 Server* displayed in list(as you are using Tomcat v8.0).
Check if "Server runtime environment" is displaying *Apache Tomcat v8.0*.
If not then click add, Browse to tomcat installation directory and select it.
Check installed JREs, if it is there.
Click next and add your project from "Available" list to "Configured" list(if there are multiple projects in available, just add the current project you want to run). Click finish. The server will be displayed in explorer, Try restarting it.
You may have already done this. :)
Still if you are unable to run, you can try this if you have maven configured project.
->Go to your project in "Project Explorer", right click the project.
->Go to properties, click on "Deployment Assembly", there check if you have Maven dependency in *Source* list. If it is not there you need to add it.

I hope it helped. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. You are right. I did all of the above except the last one. I don't have Maven dependency. So how I can add it ?